# ListView rowHasChanged r1 always equals r2

Tags: react-native, realm

I'm using Realm Native's [ListView](https://realm.io/docs/react-native/latest/#react-native-listview) which according to their site is based off React's ListView API. I'm also following Realm's `ListView` example found [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/blob/master/examples/ReactExample/components/todo-listview.js).

My problem is as follows: I currently have a `ListView` which at some point needs to be partially re-rendered, e.g. row X needs to be updated. However, the function:

```
rowHasChanged: function(r1, r2) {
    return +r1.date !== +r2.date;
}
```

...will always return `false` which means my ListView remains unchanged.

The code (within my component constructor) is as follows:

```
let objects = realm.objects('xxxx');

let dataSource = new ListView.DataSource({
   rowHasChanged: function(r1, r2) {
      return +r1.date !== +r2.date;
   }
});

this.state = {
   objects: objects,
   dataSource: dataSource.cloneWithRows(objects)
};
```

I also have an update function which will update the `dataSource` state:

```
updateObject(id, date) {
    let obj = getObjById(id);

    realm.write(() => {
       obj[0].date = date;
       ...
    });
}
```

Once the above function has executed, the `rowHasChanged` will fire. However, `r1` and `r2` are identical, such that, they both contain the new date. This subsequently means my `ListView` does not get re-rendered and the row in question will consist of the incorrect (old) date.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using this as a *temporary* solution as we're now adding an additional n*2 computation.

I've added a new function called `copyArray` (`.slice(0)` will not work due to it [shallow copying](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)).

Constructor in my component:

```
let objects = this.copyArray(realm.objects('xxxx'));

let dataSource = new ListView.DataSource({
   rowHasChanged: function(r1, r2) {
      return +r1.date !== +r2.date;
   }
});

this.state = {
   objects: objects,
   dataSource: dataSource.cloneWithRows(objects)
};
```

New function:

```
copyArray(array) {
    let newArray = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        newArray.push({
            date: array[i].date,
            ...
        });
    }

    return newArray;

}
```

Updated function:

```
updateObject(id, date) {
    let obj = getObjById(id);

    realm.write(() => {
       obj[0].date = date;
       ...
    });

    var newArray = this.copyArray(realm.objects('xxxx'));

    this.setState({
        objects: newArray,
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(newArray)
   });
}
```